# Not showing values in UI after component is loaded LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using below code for JS and HTML
JS:

```
 // Import LightningElement and api classes from lwc module
 import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
 // import getPicklistValues method from lightning/uiObjectInfoApi
 import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
 // import getObjectInfo method from lightning/uiObjectInfoApi
 import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
 // Import lead object APi from schema
 import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';
 // import Lead status field from schema
 import PICKLIST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Status';
 // import record ui service to use crud services
 import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 // import show toast
 import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
 // import update record api
 import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
'Lead.Id',
'Lead.Status'
 ];

export default class CustomPathLwc extends LightningElement {

selectedValue;
@api recordId;
@track showSpinner = false;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: LEAD_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
record;  


@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: PICKLIST_FIELD })
picklistFieldValues;




get picklistValues() {
    let itemsList = [];
    
    console.log('record value = ' , JSON.stringify(this.record));
    if (this.record.data) {
        if (!this.selectedValue && this.record.data.fields.Status.value) {
            this.selectedValue = this.record.data.fields.Status.value + '';
        }
        if (this.picklistFieldValues && this.picklistFieldValues.data && this.picklistFieldValues.data.values) {
            console.log('got picklist field data');
            let selectedUpTo = 2;
            for (let item in this.picklistFieldValues.data.values) {

                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.picklistFieldValues.data.values, item)) {
                    let classList;
                    if (this.picklistFieldValues.data.values[item].value === this.selectedValue) {
                        classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-current slds-is-active';
                        selectedUpTo++;
                    } else {
                        classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete';
                    }

                    console.log(classList);

                    itemsList.push({
                        pItem: this.picklistFieldValues.data.values[item],
                        classList: classList
                    })
                }
            }

            if (selectedUpTo > 0) {
                for (let item = 0; item < selectedUpTo; item++) {
                    itemsList[item].classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-complete';
                }
            }
            console.log('im here = ' + this.selectedValue);
            console.log('im here = itemsList' , JSON.stringify(itemsList));
            setTimeout(() => {
                eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
           }, 1000); 
            return itemsList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-path__scroller-container">
                <div class="slds-path__scroller" role="application">
                    <div class="slds-path__scroller_inner">
                        <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                            <p> test {picklistValues}</p>
                            <template if:true={picklistValues}>
                                <template for:each={picklistValues} for:item="item">
                                    <li data-value={item.pItem.value} onclick={handleSelect} key={item} class={item.classList} role="presentation">
                                         <a data-value={item.pItem.value} onclick={handleSelect} aria-selected="true" class="slds-path__link" href="javascript:void(0);" id={item.pItem.value} role="option"
                                            tabindex="0">
                                            <span class="slds-path__stage">
                                                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:check" alternative-text="Warning!" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Current Stage:</span>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="slds-path__title">{item.pItem.label}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                </template>
                            </template>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I debug the code I see that there is value in itemsList but in UI its not rendering. I checked it with

test {picklistValues}

. It dosent show any value. Seems that UI is loaded before that getpicklistValues method.

What could be the case here ? how can I resolve this

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you should avoid modifying tracked properties within getter methods. Instead, you can handle the assignment in a different context, such as a lifecycle hook or an event handler.

try like below

```
    @track itemsList = [];
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: PICKLIST_FIELD })
    picklistFieldValues({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                    this.itemsList= /* logic to set value */;
                    this.error = undefined;
                } else if (error) {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.itemsList= [];
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried with this option. But its not allowing me to add values in track property itemsList. even after removing track it dosen;t allow me to add values in it. It allows only when I declare let variable itemsList inside. But if I do that how will I refer this itemsList in html

Comment: Can you check this one https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/403740/tracked-value-updated-in-wired-method-is-not-updating-in-ui 

I don't know why UI is not updating from wired adapter